# Importing a GNU Smalltalk project into Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, gnu-smalltalk

I have about 1800 lines of GNU Smalltalk code I'd like to pull into Pharo. I've started doing it class by class, selector by selector, but it is very time consuming and tedious.

Is there a way to bulk import a project? I could easily adjust the format of the GST source files with `vi` to be more Pharo-like beforehand.

Another thing I've considered is copying a "starter" `.mcz` file, getting a feel for the format of the `source.st` file, then creating a new `source.st` with file `cat`s and `vi`. But then there's the `snapshot.bin` file which seems also to have the source in it, making that a difficult path. It seems there should be an easier way. I've Google'd for it with different phrases but haven't hit anything.

Comment: Very good question. I'm posting this on the list to give it more exposure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting it in Monticello (.mcz) format is overkill for migrating.  Just get it into fileout format (http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/1105) and once you've loaded it into Pharo via filein, then you can create a Monticello package using the GUI if you want.

An quick way to see what fileout format involves (mainly just putting '!' in the right places):

1. Load up Pharo
2. Open a Browser
3. Right click on a class and select 'File Out' from the menu
4. You should see a file called [Classname].st in the directory you launched Pharo from

Comment: This looks promising. I took one of my modules and quickly converted it to the filein format. I used the Pharo 5.0 Tools > File Browser to find the filein file and selected it. it showed up in the preview window. I clicked "Filein" and... nothing happened. I also tried right-clicking the file name, selecting "Filein entire file" or "Install into new change set" and nothing happened.

Comment: fileIn (or chunk) format is a bit tricky as for the ! mark signs. Sometimes you need two of them with a whitespace between in unsuspected places... You should check that.carefully And the final solution shoudl be debugging what happens when you do "File in", you will quickly find the wring assumption if you are patience enough to go Into, and Into.

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro OK, good suggestion. I may have oversimplified my conversion process or missed some subtlety in it. I can check it.

Comment: I either neglected to refresh the system browser first time I did the import, or making sure I included the `SystemOrganization` line, but it works great now.

Answer (score 3):

Say you have two classes, `LuckyClass1` a subclass of `Object` and `LuckyClass2` subclass of `LuckyClass1`. And let's say your name is `LuckyName`. And let's say you want to put your code into the package `Lucky-Package1`.

```
Object subclass: #LuckyClass1
LuckyClass1 subclass: #LuckyClass2
```

Class `LuckyClass1` with an instance side method `luckyInstanceSideMethod1`, a class side method `luckyClassSideMethod1` and instance side variable `luckyInstanceSideVariable1` and class side variable `LuckyClassSideVariable1`.

Similarly class `LuckyClass2` with an instance side method `luckyInstanceSideMethod1`, a class side method `luckyClassSideMethod1` and an additional instance side variable `luckyInstanceSideVariable2` and class side variable `LuckyClassSideVariable2`.

Method references would look like this

```
LuckyClass1>>#luckyInstanceSideMethod1
LuckyClass1 class>>#luckyClassSideMethod1
LuckyClass2>>#luckyInstanceSideMethod1
LuckyClass2 class>>#luckyClassSideMethod1
```

On Linux/Mac OS X, do

`vi Lucky-Package1-unix.st`

to put in a file named `Lucky-Package1-unix.st`
something like

```
Object subclass: #LuckyClass1
    instanceVariableNames: 'luckyInstanceSideVariable1'
    classVariableNames: 'LuckyClassSideVariable1'
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Lucky-Package1'!

!LuckyClass1 methodsFor: 'lucky instance side protocol 1' stamp: 'LuckyName 6/8/2016 17:05'!
luckyInstanceSideMethod1
    ^ luckyInstanceSideVariable1 := 'lucky instance side'
! !

!LuckyClass1 class methodsFor: 'lucky class side protocol 1' stamp: 'LuckyName 6/8/2016 17:06'!
luckyClassSideMethod1
    ^ LuckyClassSideVariable1 := 'lucky class side'
! !

LuckyClass1 subclass: #LuckyClass2
    instanceVariableNames: 'luckyInstanceSideVariable2'
    classVariableNames: 'LuckyClassSideVariable2'
    poolDictionaries: ''
    category: 'Lucky-Package1'!

!LuckyClass2 methodsFor: 'lucky instance side protocol 1' stamp: 'LuckyName 6/8/2016 17:15'!
luckyInstanceSideMethod1
    ^ super luckyInstanceSideMethod1, ' subclass'
! !

!LuckyClass2 class methodsFor: 'lucky class side protocol 1' stamp: 'LuckyName 6/8/2016 17:17'!
luckyClassSideMethod1
    ^ super luckyClassSideMethod1, ' subclass'
! !
```

In fact, you can cut & paste the preceding block.

Then convert linefeeds to carriage returns or else Pharo will complain. This is important. If you are on Linux/Mac OS X you can use the following

```
cat Lucky-Package1-unix.st | tr \\n \\r > Lucky-Package1-pharo.st
```

On Windows I would still use bash, vi, cat, tr from git-scm https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then file in `Lucky-Package1-pharo.st`. It should appear in the `Lucky-Package1` package in System Browser.

Comment: See my comment to the other answer. I created a filein formatted file, but Pharo quietly did nothing when I tried importing it.

Comment: Sorry. Can't help you if you are not willing to try out my solution. Good luck.

Comment: No need to be snarky. I did not say I wasn't willing to try your suggestion at all, did I? I plan to examine what I did try first, and if that fails, try your simplified example as a baseline. I may reverse the order of those. Don't know yet.

Comment: I wrote a detailed sample of what works for me. I can answer questions
about that. Not about some file you did not show me on an unknown
platform. You say 'I created a filein formatted file but Pharo quietly
did nothing when I tried importing it'. Right. What is one to make out
of that? Where is your file or a snippet from it?  Did you convert the
linefeeds to carriage returns before you tried to file it in? What
version of Pharo do you have? What platform are you running Pharo
on? Windows/Linux/Mac OS X? What version? After 'Pharo did nothing',
where did you look for your code?